# Editing sstreams in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
    std::vector<int> vect;

    std::stringstream ss(str);

    for (int i=1; ss >> i;) {
        vect.push_back(i);
        if (ss.peek() == ',')
            ss.ignore();
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vect[i] << std::endl;

}
```

I have this code. I'm trying to remove the first and last values from the string. I have tried deleting those values before getting to the `for` loop but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not remove the first and the last value from the *vector* instead? Or just skip don't add the value to the vector for the first number (keep track of that using a boolean flag) and the last value (when `peek()` doesn't return a comma character)?

Comment: Hi Al-ameen, welcome to StackOverflow! Please be more specific. *What* does not work? What exactly did you do? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Your code shows that you understand how `if` and `for` statements work. That's all you need to do this. You can simply use an `if` statement to avoid adding the first number to the vector, and then after the loop remove the last value from the vector. Which part of this do you have a difficulty with, and what would be the nature of your difficulty?

Comment: The question is very unclear. Is your desired outcome a `vector<int>{2,3,4,5}` or the string `"2,3,4,5"`?

Comment: Are all the values positive single-digit numbers? Two of the answers make that assumption and won't work unless it's true.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the last and first characters from the string

```
str = str.substr(1, str.size() - 2);
```

Or

```
str.erase(str.begin());
str.erase(--str.end());
```

To remove the two last and two first characters from the string

```
str = str.substr(2, str.size() - 4);
```

Or

```
    str.erase(str.begin(), str.begin()+2);
    str.erase(str.end()-2, str.end());
```

Comment: Did you perchance not test the first answer? Adding "str = str.substr(1, str.size() - 2)" yields no output at all. Changing the first number might help. Changing both numbers might even yield what OP wanted.

Comment: First option doesn't work, second is good, you don't need `iterator` library though.

Comment: @anastaciu How didn't the first option work? It logically works and I tested it!!

Comment: Sorry, bad frasing, it works in a general manner, but doesn't work when appplied to the OP's code https://onlinegdb.com/BJVL1G1fI

Comment: @anastaciu He asked "I'm trying to remove the first and last values from the string". Any way I provided more options. thanks

Comment: Better, my point is the solution should work for the objective, you're right though, the OP should state that the objective is a vector without the first and last values of the string.

Comment: @anastaciu You're both assuming the values are only positive single-digit numbers. That's not stated in the question and I've left them a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: @Blastfurnace It's stated implicitly in the given string `"1,2,3,4,5,6"` all the values are only positive single-digit numbers

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to point out that the question talks about **values** and not **characters**. Maybe your code is exactly what they want...

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes, that's a good point, the code is adapted to the string given, that cenario is not contemplated in our code, Ted Lyngmo does take that in consideration, let's wait for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to messing with the actual `stringstream`. Extract the `int`s and remove the first and last from the resulting vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";

    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::vector<int> vect;

    while(ss) {                    // is the stream in a good state
        if(int v; ss >> v) {       // try to extract an int
            vect.push_back(v);     // success, save it
        } else if(not ss.eof()) {  // check that the stream is not depleated
            ss.clear();            // clear the failstate
            ss.ignore();           // ignore 1 char
        } // else leave the stream in a failed state to exit the while loop
    }

    // erase the last int in the vector
    if(not vect.empty()) vect.erase(std::prev(vect.end()));

    // erase the first int in the vector
    if(not vect.empty()) vect.erase(vect.begin());

    for (int val : vect)
        std::cout << val << '\n';

}
```